# how to switch two tables on different image click on first row using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to create a 1 page html website.I have already done it in french language now i am trying to add an option at the top of my website to translate language between french or english.

The idea is to have a table which contains a button of flag of France and england (french and english) in first row (something like this:http://prntscr.com/6yq4t2 ) now on changing the flag should switch to another table whose contents are written in the language of flag clicked using html and the existing table will be replaced by the table of flag-language clicked (actually there are 2 tables(one at a time) having English and French contents which must switch on click to flags on the first row of default table-which is french).

see this part in code:

```
<h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">
      Language translation:
      <img width="18" height="10" src="http://www.mapsofworld.com/images/world-countries-flags/france-flag.gif" alt="" onclick="myFunctionFrench()" />
      <img width="18" height="10" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/mortalengines/images/b/b6/English_flag.png/revision/latest?cb=20100614220751" alt="" onclick="myFunctionEnglish()" />

</h1>
```

I have all my html like this (it don't contain code for English table but it will have the table of same html code except that the written content are in English and the switching has to be done between these two tables on respective flag selection):

```
<!DOCTYPE PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Axestrack</title>
    <!--general stylesheet-->
    <style type="text/css">
        p {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li {
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        td {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        ul, ol {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .tab {
            margin-left: 40px;
            margin-right: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="img_home"></div>
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center" style="margin: 0px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td valign="top">
                    <!--container-->
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="11" align="center" width="621" bgcolor="#f7f3e6" background="images/bg-stamp-2.jpg" style="border-width:11px; border-color:#ccc; border-style:solid; background-color:#f7f3e6; background-image: url('http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/bg-stamp-2.jpg'); background-position: right top !important; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" border="0" style="border: none; ">
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="padding-bottom: 13px;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">
                                                    Language translation:
                                                    <img width="18" height="10" src="http://www.mapsofworld.com/images/world-countries-flags/france-flag.gif" alt="" onclick="myFunctionFrench()" />
                                                    <img width="18" height="10" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/mortalengines/images/b/b6/English_flag.png/revision/latest?cb=20100614220751" alt="" onclick="myFunctionEnglish()" />

                                                </h1>
                                                <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit"><img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 19px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Michel</h1>
                                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Résidence étudiante</h1>
                                                </td>                                               
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr></tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit"><img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Recherche d'emploi(développement C/ C++/ C#/ Silverlight/ Wpf/ Asp.Net/ MVC-MVVM) </h1>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit"><img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <!--Formation-->
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Formation: </h1>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <!-- Paris -->
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2012-2014 :</h1>
                                    <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">
                                        Master en Génie informatique à  paris. (Diplôme d'ingénieur)
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!---->           
        </tbody>

    </table>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" colspan="2"><img width="599" height="6" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/double-spacer.jpg" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>


    <!--faltu kaam here -->
    <script>
        function myFunctionFrench() {
            document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
        function myFunctionEnglish() {
            document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

How to implement this switching of 2 tables on flag click which contains the language-flag in first row. Any idea ? (please take my html code as reference to answer my question).

Could some one please help me in doing this ?

Comment: You could write the respective language parts in a `<div>` each, and and use `display:block;` or `display:none` to show and hide them respectively.

Comment: @buki  thanks buki... could you please let me know how i should  my html code to get it done ? (lets assume that i also have html written for english translation as well, so that we have both french and english content and we can switch on both the divs on flag click). You can use my html running code.

Answer (score 1):

Write all the divs (and put class on them, like for example : `.french` ) in both languages and then use `jQuery` as following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#frenchFlag").click(function(){ //When you click on the French flag
       $(".french").show(); //Show the divs with the class .french
       $(".english").hide(); //Hide the divs with the class .english
  });
   $("#englishFlag").click(function(){ //Same thing
      $(".french").hide();
      $(".english").show();
   });
});
```

Obviously you'll hide either the divs with the class `.french` or the divs with `.english` at the start of the loading of your page (basically in your

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 //Write here, for example if your website is in French by default :
  $(".french").show();
  $(".english").hide()
});
```

Comment: i am new to html and javasxcript . so as i understand it is javascript code and my content is written in html statically . How to write html on    $(".french").show(); call ?

Comment: Just add a new `<script type="text/javascript"> put the function there </script>` in your `<head> </head>` (you can also separate it in a new file). Also, please add those two lines for the `jQuery` to work : `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button id="bt1">In English</button>
<button id="bt2">In French</button>

<div>
    <div id="one">
 <table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th>Language</th>
    <th>Name</th>  
    <th>Pattern</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>English</td>
    <td>c#</td>  
    <td>MVC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>English</td>
    <td>Java</td>  
    <td>J2EE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>English</td>
    <td>.Net</td>  
    <td>MVC4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 
 </div>
    <div id="two" style="display:none">
 <table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th>Language</th>
    <th>Name</th>  
    <th>Pattern</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>French</td>
    <td>PHP</td>  
    <td>MVC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>French</td>
    <td>Java</td>  
    <td>J2EE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>French</td>
    <td>.Net</td>  
    <td>MVC4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 
 </div>
</div>
<script>
function swap(one, two) {
    document.getElementById(one).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(two).style.display = 'none';
}
document.getElementById('bt1').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    swap('one','two');
});
document.getElementById('bt2').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    swap('two','one');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of button you can replace your image.

```
<div id="bt1" ><img src="english.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="20"></div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this. The results are horrible.

Comment: @gihan i dont have to do exact french to english translation..i have to write manually the text for engliah because exact frenc->english translation is not correct always.

Comment: In your code the french translation will be placed below the english translation.. But i want one at a time.. I mean first if i select english then i selct french . in ur case it wil have both ...but i want just 1 at 1 selection at same place (not like french is below and english is above)

Comment: you can customize JS function to fill same div with different content.To get some idea refer following link.http://jsfiddle.net/8f8jt/. Note : you should add Jquary1.5 or above lib file into your HTML page

Comment: @gihan thanks but the problem is in my case the contents are written in html code(example this line: Recherche d'emploi(développement C/ C++/ C#/ Silverlight/ Wpf/ Asp.Net/ MVC-MVVM)) is written in "<h1 ..../h1>" and u use javascript for it. I dotn know how to do ur javascript stuff in html. i mean i will have all my contents written in html inside a table in just 1 language and changing language  will replace the content of previous language table in to the clicked language table . (there are 2 tables using html containing fernch and english content which will switch on language selction)

Comment: I want to explain again. for example i have two tables in whose contents written using html , one for english and another for french and i want to switch them by changing the language  each time. see this contaisn flags at top (and it dsiplays fernch language content in first glance) http://prntscr.com/6yq14j  this table will be replaced by another table having content in english using html code(not java script). How to achieve this. Sorry for the troubles :'(

Comment: and this option of flag for changing the language is located in first row of table (which is another problem because click on image of first row will  change the contents of all the table/or cotents of all the rows below).

Answer (score 0):

You could write your HTML like this:

```
<div id='english' style='display: none'>
    [your complete english HTML]
</div>
<div id='french' style='display: block'>
    [your complete french HTML]
</div>
```

And for your buttons:

```
<img [...] onClick="document.getElementById('english').style.display=none; document.getElementById('french').style.display=block;">
```

For the french version. The english switches the display attribute, of course.

Comment: thanks but how to put in my html context thats what i am not able to understand. I mean by default code should show french version (the flag part will be common for both language) and on england flad it should show english version. how to do implement that using my code thats wht i am not abel to understand.

Comment: I edited my answer to ensure that default french will be visible, english will not. Does that help you?