# how to switch between two tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created one HTML page. I have done it in just french language now I am trying to add an option at the top of my website to translate language between French and English (there are 2 language flags in the link in paragraph below).

My idea is to have a table which contains a button of flag of France and England (French and English) in first row (something like this: http://prntscr.com/6yq4t2 ) now on changing the flag should switch to another table whose contents are written in the language of flag clicked using HTML and the existing table will be replaced by the table of flag-language clicked (actually there are 2 tables(one displayed at a time) having English and French contents which must switch on click to flags on the first row of default table-which is french).

See this part in code:

```
<h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">
      Language translation:
      <img width="18" height="10" src="http://www.mapsofworld.com/images/world-countries-flags/france-flag.gif" alt="" onclick="myFunctionFrench()" />
      <img width="18" height="10" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/mortalengines/images/b/b6/English_flag.png/revision/latest?cb=20100614220751" alt="" onclick="myFunctionEnglish()" />        
</h1>
```

I have my HTML code below (it doesn't contain code for English table but it is assumed that the table have same HTML code except that the written content are in English and the switching has to be done between these two tables on respective flag selection):

```
<!DOCTYPE PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Axestrack</title>
    <!--general stylesheet-->
    <style type="text/css">
        p {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li {
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }    
        td {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        ul, ol {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .tab {
            margin-left: 40px;
            margin-right: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="img_home"></div>
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" align="center" style="margin: 0px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td valign="top">
                    <!--container-->
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="11" align="center" width="621" bgcolor="#f7f3e6" background="images/bg-stamp-2.jpg" style="border-width:11px; border-color:#ccc; border-style:solid; background-color:#f7f3e6; background-image: url('http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/bg-stamp-2.jpg'); background-position: right top !important; background-repeat: repeat-x;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" border="0" style="border: none; ">
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="padding-bottom: 13px;">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">
                                                    Language translation:
                                                    <img width="18" height="10" src="http://www.mapsofworld.com/images/world-countries-flags/france-flag.gif" alt="" onclick="myFunctionFrench()" />
                                                    <img width="18" height="10" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/mortalengines/images/b/b6/English_flag.png/revision/latest?cb=20100614220751" alt="" onclick="myFunctionEnglish()" />    
                                                </h1>
                                                <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit"><img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 19px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Michel</h1>
                                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Résidence étudiante</h1>
                                                </td>                                               
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr></tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit"><img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:#33384f;">Recherche d'emploi(développement C/ C++/ C#/ Silverlight/ Wpf/ Asp.Net/ MVC-MVVM) </h1>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="padding:inherit"><img width="650" height="18" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/header-top.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <!--Formation-->
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px; color:red;">Formation: </h1>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <!-- Paris -->
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="511" style="padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 21px;">
                                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-size: 12px;">2012-2014 :</h1>
                                    <p class="tab" style="margin-right:0;font-size: 12px;">
                                        Master en Génie informatique à  paris. (Diplôme d'ingénieur)
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!---->           
        </tbody>

    </table>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" colspan="2"><img width="599" height="6" src="http://www.axestrack.com/wp-content/uploads/double-spacer.jpg" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>


    <!--faltu kaam here -->
    <script>
        function myFunctionFrench() {
            document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
        function myFunctionEnglish() {
            document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

How to implement this switching of 2 tables on flag click which contains the language-flag in first row. Any idea ? (please take my html code as reference to answer my question).

Could some one please help me in doing this ?

**After Wrick7 suggestion**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script>        
        (function ()
        {

            $(".frc-tab").show();
            $(".eng-tab").hide();
            $('.eng').on('click', function (event)
            {
                alert('eng click');
                $('.eng-tab').show();
                $('.frc-tab').hide();
            });
            $('.frc').on('click', function (event)
            {
                alert('french click');
                $('.eng-tab').hide();
                $('.frc-tab').show();
            });
        })();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="eng">english</button>
        <button class="frc">french</button>
    </div>
    <div class="eng-tab">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>english</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="frc-tab">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <td>french</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is:
http://prntscr.com/6zdj0r

Comment: You could save the two tables as separate html files, and then use AJAX to load which ever one the user chooses.  If you are using Jquery, it could be done simply with the .load() function: https://api.jquery.com/load/ If you would prefer to use just JavaScript look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: If u use jquery, put the two tables in a <div> each. then onclick of the <img> switch hide and show them

Comment: @testing Test seems like both are same questions please remove one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891972/how-to-switch-two-tables-on-different-image-click-on-first-row-using-html

Comment: here is a fiddle to see it working http://jsbin.com/qajufo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @wrick17 that is the correct approach, have 2 divs one for english one for french - have one show by default with a hidden style and on button click swap their hide/show

Comment: @wrick17 thanks but when i run ur given code by adding the javascript part in scipt in head then it gives the view like this http://prntscr.com/6zdi2q  and when i enter the  alert('eng click'); and  alert('french click'); inside the click event of both then they never popup. I am not able to understand why. Could you please explain the reason for this and write answer below so that i would be able to mark it as answer as well . please also see the edit of question.

Comment: @testingTest so have you included the jquery lib? see that you are adding the jquery lib file before the custom script. and put the script at the end inside the body. see. like this. http://jsbin.com/qajufo/2/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You can set one table with visibility hidden and another with visible and then when a button is pressed you just change it in js....

```js
function changeDisplay(view1,view2){
  //var statev1 = document.getElementById(view1).style.visibility;
  //var statev2 = document.getElementById(view2).style.visibility;
  //if (statev1 === 'visible'){
    document.getElementById(view1).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById(view2).style.visibility = 'visible';
  /*}else{
    document.getElementById(view2).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById(view1).style.visibility = 'visible';
  }*/
}
```

```css
.switch6 {  max-width: 17em;  margin: 0 auto;}
.switch6-light > span, 
.switch-toggle > span {  color: #000000; }
.switch6-light span span, 
.switch6-light label, 
.switch-toggle span span, 
.switch-toggle label {  color: #2b2b2b; }
.switch-toggle a, 
.switch6-light span span { display: none; }
.switch6-light { display: block; height: 30px; position: relative; overflow: visible; padding: 0px; margin-left:0px; }
.switch6-light * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.switch6-light a { display: block; transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s; }
.switch6-light label, 
.switch6-light > span { line-height: 30px; vertical-align: middle;}
.switch6-light label {font-weight: 700; margin-bottom: px; max-width: 100%;}
.switch6-light input:focus ~ a, 
.switch6-light input:focus + label { outline: 1px dotted rgb(136, 136, 136); }
.switch6-light input { position: absolute; opacity: 0; z-index: 5; }
.switch6-light input:checked ~ a { right: 0%; }
.switch6-light > span { position: absolute; left: -100px; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding-right: 100px; text-align: left; }
.switch6-light > span span { position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 5; display: block; width: 50%; margin-left: 100px; text-align: center; }
.switch6-light > span span:last-child { left: 50%; }
.switch6-light a { position: absolute; right: 50%; top: 0px; z-index: 4; display: block; width: 50%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; }
```

```html
<div class="switch6">
  <label class="switch6-light">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span>
        <span onclick="changeDisplay('sign','log');">Log-In</span>
        <span onclick="changeDisplay('log','sign');">Sign-In</span>
      </span>
      <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
  </label>
</div>
```